# Use of objective function with nlopt library in cpp

Tags: c++, nlopt

So I'm trying to solve a non linear equation with the [nlopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_C-plus-plus_Reference/) library.
I created a Class called Optimizer. Within this class I'm trying to build all the functions I need (objective function, constraints). My objective function is defined like this:

```
double Optimizer::myvfunc(const std::vector<double> &x, const std::vector<double> &grad, void *func_data) {

    if (!grad.empty()){
        build_gradient(x,grad);  
    }

    double term=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < support_points; i++) {
       term += calc_distance_term(i,x);
    }

    return term;
}
```

Now I want to call a method Optimizer::optimize(), which then  sets all the constraints and requirements for the nlopt-algorithm to start. I'm using:

```
double Optimizer::optimize() {
    nlopt::opt optimizer(nlopt::LD_SLSQP, (u_int)3*support_points);
    optimizer.set_min_objective(myvfunc, NULL); // compile error

    return 0;
}
```

This is where I get a compile error, which I can't explain.

> Parameter type mismatch: Incompatible number of arguments in function types

I tried to stick with the Tutorial as much as possible, but why do I get this error?

Comment: this is because your function is a member function of optimizer. (That means it really takes 4 args not 3). The tutorial uses a non member function. Change the myvfunc to static or make it non member func

Comment: @pm100 Thanks for the fast reply, but this didnt solve the problem. The problem was that I defined the parameter &grad with the prefix const. The typedef vfunc expects no const on the second parameter. Though the tutorial uses a non member function, you can also define your function as a member function without receiving a compiling error. If I encounter a problem because of this when running the algorithm, i will leave a note here.